# Multi client server in Dart

Tags: tcp, dart

If I want to make a simple multi client TCP server in Java, I would just wait for connections and make another thread which use a thread-pool to handle each one.

I am wondering if this piece of code will allow me the same behavior without explicitly opening a thread for each client in Dart:

```
ServerSocket.bind('127.0.0.1', 4041)
  .then((serverSocket) {
    serverSocket.listen((socket) {
      socket.transform(utf8.decoder).listen(handleClient);
    });
  });

void handleClient(Socket socket){
  // do something
}
```

If it doesn't, how will I come about implementing such behavior? In a `Darty` way preferably.

Answer (score 2):

Both the Aqueduct and Angel web frameworks support pre-spawned Isolates to ensure that all your cores can be in play.

Comment: Aren't both of them for Web applications? I plan on using this for a small mobile application project i'm working on.

Comment: The server-side components provide a RESTful API and server-side database access.  People are using them with Flutter apps, yes.

Comment: `package:angel_framework` is the core server library, and can be used by itself (in Flutter too, for that regard). The more "application-y" functionality, like WebSockets, static servers, databases, etc. is in separate, complementary packages.

Answer (score 0):

Dart uses single-threaded concurrency by default.
If you want code to run on another thread, you need to create a new Isolate explicitely.

Dart supports having more than one thread listening on the same IP and port and automatically distributes incoming connections to listening threads.

See also

- https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-isolate/dart-isolate-library.html
- https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/isolate

Comment: So I'll need to open an Isolate for every client?
Do you suggest i do it in the _handleClient_ function or in _listen_?

Comment: You don't need to, only if you want to have each request handled in another isolate. Creating isolates for each request is a bad idea because isolate startup is slow. A single thread can handle many requests just fine. You can startup a number of isolates in advance and let Dart share requests among them to share load among multiple isolates.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

edit (pubspec.yaml) file and add:

```
dependencies:
  network_info_plus: ^2.1.3
  r_get_ip: ^0.1.1
```

server.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:r_get_ip/r_get_ip.dart';


class server extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  SocketServerState createState() {
    SocketServerState pageState = SocketServerState();
    return pageState;
  }
}

class SocketServerState extends State<server> {
  final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  String localIP = "";

  ServerSocket? serverSocket;
  List <Socket> clientList = [];

  Socket? curentClient;
  int port = 9000;

  TextEditingController msgCon = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    stopServer();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getIP();
    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Server")),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          ipInfoArea(),
          submitArea(),
          clientsListArea(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget ipInfoArea() {
    return Card(
      child: ListTile(
        dense: true,
        leading: Text("IP"),
        title: Text(localIP),
        trailing: RaisedButton(
          child: Text((serverSocket == null) ? "Start" : "Stop"),
          onPressed: (serverSocket == null) ? startServer : stopServer,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget clientsListArea() {
    return Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: clientList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            Socket client = clientList[index];
            return Container(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Container(
                color: (curentClient == client)? Color(0x410EA598):Color(0x0) ,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
                padding:
                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
                child: InkWell(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        'Client ${clientList.indexOf(client!)}',
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        curentClient!.remoteAddress.address,
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),

                    ],
                  ),
                  onTap: (){
                    setState(() {
                      curentClient = client;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }


  Widget submitArea() {
    return  Row(children: [
      Expanded(
        child: TextField(
          controller: msgCon,
        ),
      ),
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.send),
        color: Colors.blue,
        disabledColor: Colors.grey,
        onPressed: (curentClient != null) ? submitMessage : null,
      ),
    ],
    );
  }

  void getIP() async {
    var ip = await RGetIp.internalIP;
    setState(() {
      localIP = ip!;
    });
  }

  void startServer() async {
    serverSocket = await ServerSocket.bind(InternetAddress.anyIPv4, port, shared: true);

    serverSocket!.listen((client) {
      curentClient = client;

      clientList.add(client);

      client.listen((onData) {

        String msg = utf8.decode(onData);

        showMessage(msg, client);


      },
        onError: (e) {
          disconnectClient(client);
        },
        onDone: () {
          disconnectClient(client);
        },
      );
    }
    );
  }


  void stopServer() {
    for(int i=0; i<clientList.length; i++){
      disconnectClient(clientList[i]);
    }
    serverSocket!.close();
    clientList.clear();
    setState(() {
      serverSocket = null;
    });
  }

  void disconnectClient(Socket client) {
    if (curentClient != null) {
      client!.close();
      client!.destroy();
      clientList.remove(client);
    }

    setState(() {
      if(clientList.length != 0){
        curentClient = clientList[0];
      }else {
        curentClient = null;
      }
    });
  }

  void submitMessage() {
    if (msgCon.text.isEmpty) return;

    sendMessage(msgCon.text);
    msgCon.clear();
  }

  void sendMessage(String message) {
    curentClient!.encoding = utf8;
    curentClient!.write("$message");
  }



  void showMessage(String s,Socket client) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context){
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Client ${clientList.indexOf(client!)}'),
            content: Text(s),
            actions: [MaterialButton(child:Text('OK'), color: Colors.grey, onPressed: (){Navigator.pop(context);})],
          );
        }
    );
  }
}
```

client.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:r_get_ip/r_get_ip.dart';



class client extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  SocketClientState createState() {
    SocketClientState pageState = SocketClientState();
    return pageState;
  }
}

class SocketClientState extends State<client> {
  final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  String localIP = "";
  int port = 9000;

  bool isConnected = false;

  TextEditingController ipCon = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController msgCon = TextEditingController();

  Socket? clientSocket;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getIP();
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    disconnectFromServer();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void getIP() async {
    var ip = await RGetIp.internalIP;
    setState(() {
      localIP = ip!;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        key: scaffoldKey,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Client"),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            ipInfoArea(),
            connectArea(),
            submitArea(),
          ],
        ));
  }

  Widget ipInfoArea() {
    return Card(
      child: ListTile(
        dense: true,
        leading: Text("IP"),
        title: Text(localIP),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget connectArea() {
    return Card(
      child: ListTile(
        dense: true,
        leading: Text("Server IP"),
        title: TextField(
          controller: ipCon,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              contentPadding:
              const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
              isDense: true,
              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade300),
              ),
              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade400),
              ),
              filled: true,
              fillColor: Colors.grey[50]),
        ),
        trailing: RaisedButton(
          child: Text((clientSocket != null) ? "Disconnect" : "Connect"),
          onPressed:
          (clientSocket != null) ? disconnectFromServer : connectToServer,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  Widget submitArea() {
    return Row(children: [
      Expanded(
        child: TextField(
          controller: msgCon,
        ),
      ),
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.send),
        color: Colors.blue,
        disabledColor: Colors.grey,
        onPressed: (clientSocket != null) ? submitMessage : null,
      ),
    ],
    );
  }

  void connectToServer() async {
    print("Destination Address: ${ipCon.text}");
    
    Socket.connect(ipCon.text, port, timeout: Duration(seconds: 5))
        .then((socket) {
      setState(() {
        isConnected = true;
        clientSocket = socket;
      });

      socket.listen(
            (onData) {

          String msg = utf8.decode(onData);
          showMessage(msg);
        },
        onDone: onDone,
        onError: onError,
      );
    }).catchError((e) {

    });
  }

  void onDone() {
    disconnectFromServer();
  }

  void onError(e) {
    print("onError: $e");
    disconnectFromServer();
  }

  void disconnectFromServer() {
    print("disconnectFromServer");
    isConnected = false;
    clientSocket?.close();
    setState(() {
      clientSocket = null;
    });
  }

  void sendMessage(String message) {
    clientSocket!.encoding = utf8;
    clientSocket!.write("$message");
  }
  

  void submitMessage() {
    if (msgCon.text.isEmpty) return;

    sendMessage(msgCon.text);
    msgCon.clear();
    setState(() {

    });
  }


  void showMessage(String s) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context){
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text("Server"),
            content: Text(s),
            actions: [MaterialButton(child:Text('OK'), color: Colors.grey, onPressed: (){Navigator.pop(context);})],
          );
        }
    );
  }
}
```

main.dart

```
// @dart=2.9

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'sever.dart';

import 'client.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: "My App",
    home: MyApp(),
  )
  );
}


class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: InkWell(
              child: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                color: Colors.green,
                child: Text('Server',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),),
              ),
              onTap: (){
                Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => server()));
              },
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: InkWell(
              child: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Text('Client',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),),
              ),
              onTap: (){
                print('client');
                Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => client()));
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

}
```